# tlmgr does not execute an update

Tags: texlive, updating

unfortunately I am coming to you with another problem. I wanted to update `TeX Live 2013` on my 64 bit Win7 system using `tlmgr`. So normally I use the GUI, but that did not start up. I hopped on the command line (admin mode) and typed:

```
 tlmgr update --all --self
```

And I got the following error message, which also results in no update being performed:

```
 Unknown docfile tag:  texmf-dist/doc/latex/pythontex/pythontex_quickstart.pdf details=""Quick start" documentation" at C:/texlive/2013/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 127, <TMP> line 128161.
```

What should I do now?